# Which are the pgbouncer limits?

Tags: pgbouncer

I have a  PostgreSQL 9.4 running on Debian 7.

My question is simple,  there is a  connection limit for pgbouncer?

if I set  a   postgres's max_connections to 256.

Can I set a pgbouncer with following values:

1. **max_client_conn** to 4096 or greater
2. **default_pool_size** to 250,
3. **reserve_pool_size** to 4096, same to max_client_conn

And, because I have slow querys, more than 3 minutes in a big,big table,
    **reserve_pool_size** to 120

if I need increase those values , should I change the kernel settings?

How can I calculate  those values for a best  pgbouncer performance?

Regards.